# Error when uploading image from gallery to server

Tags: android, file-upload

I am getting a error when I try to run my application. I can start my application and pick the image but then the application crash. I really don't know what is wrong ?

The error message is as below:

`11-15 12:32:44.167: E/AndroidRuntime(24617): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/328 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.example.testuploade4/com.example.testuploade4.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

Here is my android class:

```
package com.example.testuploade4;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int SELECT_IMAGE = 1;
    String selectedPath;

    String urlString = "http://jadder.dk/sjov/uploade1.php";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        openGallery();
    }

    public void openGallery() {

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image "),
                SELECT_IMAGE);
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_IMAGE) {
                System.out.println("SELECT_IMAGE");
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedPath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                System.out.println("SELECT_IMAGE Path : " + selectedPath);
                doFileUpload();
            }
        }
    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }

    private void doFileUpload() {
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        DataInputStream inStream = null;
        String lineEnd = "rn";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        String responseFromServer = "";
        try {
            // ------------------ CLIENT REQUEST
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(
                    selectedPath));
            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            // Allow Outputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            // Don't use a cached copy.
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            // Use a post method.
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                    + selectedPath + "\"" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            // create a buffer of maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }
            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
            // close streams
            Log.e("Debug", "File is written");
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
        }
        // ------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
        try {
            inStream = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            String str;

            while ((str = inStream.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.e("Debug", "Server Response " + str);
            }
            inStream.close();

        } catch (IOException ioex) {
            Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
// Where the file is going to be placed
$target_path = "uploads/";

/* Add the original filename to our target path.
Result is "uploads/filename.extension" */
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']).
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    echo "filename: " .  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
    echo "target_path: " .$target_path;
}
?>
```

Now i am getting a new error. I Think ther problem is in the php code but i i dont know:

The errror message is:

File is written
Server Response 
There was an error uploading the file, please try again!filename: target_path: uploads/

EDIT:

```
package com.example.testuploade4;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int SELECT_IMAGE = 1;
    String selectedPath;

    String urlString = "http://jadder.dk/sjov/uploade1.php";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        openGallery();
    }

    public void openGallery() {

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image "),
                SELECT_IMAGE);
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_IMAGE) {
                System.out.println("SELECT_IMAGE");
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedPath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                System.out.println("SELECT_IMAGE Path : " + selectedPath);
                doFileUpload();
            }
        }
    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }

    private void doFileUpload() {

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                HttpURLConnection conn = null;
                DataOutputStream dos = null;
                DataInputStream inStream = null;
                String lineEnd = "rn";
                String twoHyphens = "--";
                String boundary = "*****";
                int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
                byte[] buffer;
                int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
                String responseFromServer = "";
                try {
                    // ------------------ CLIENT REQUEST
                    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(selectedPath));
                    // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                    URL url = new URL(urlString);
                    // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
                    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    // Allow Inputs
                    conn.setDoInput(true);
                    // Allow Outputs
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);
                    // Don't use a cached copy.
                    conn.setUseCaches(false);
                    // Use a post method.
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                    dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\"" + selectedPath + "\"" + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    // create a buffer of maximum size
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                    // read file and write it into form...
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    while (bytesRead > 0) {
                        dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    }
                    // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
                    // close streams
                    Log.e("Debug", "File is written");
                    fileInputStream.close();
                    dos.flush();
                    dos.close();
                } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                    Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
                }
                // ------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
                try {
                    inStream = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                    String str;

                    while ((str = inStream.readLine()) != null) {
                        Log.e("Debug", "Server Response " + str);
                    }
                    inStream.close();

                } catch (IOException ioex) {
                    Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
                }

                return null;
            }
        }.execute();

    }

}
```

The Logcat:

```
11-15 13:30:16.211: D/libEGL(26221): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
11-15 13:30:16.211: D/libEGL(26221): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
11-15 13:30:16.211: D/libEGL(26221): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
11-15 13:30:16.221: I/Adreno200-EGL(26221): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:265>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM Build: Iabe52cfaeae4c5fab1acacfe6f056ba15fa93274
11-15 13:30:16.251: D/OpenGLRenderer(26221): Enabling debug mode 0
11-15 13:30:16.351: D/dalvikvm(26221): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 104K, 2% free 9228K/9376K, paused 15ms, total 16ms
11-15 13:30:20.454: I/System.out(26221): SELECT_IMAGE
11-15 13:30:20.465: I/System.out(26221): SELECT_IMAGE Path : /storage/emulated/0/Download/560843_531646073574745_683776063_n.jpg
11-15 13:30:20.575: D/dalvikvm(26221): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 103K, 2% free 9574K/9756K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
11-15 13:30:20.595: E/Debug(26221): File is written
11-15 13:30:21.275: E/Debug(26221): Server Response There was an error uploading the file, please try again!filename: target_path: uploads/
```

Answer (score 0):

Youur `doFileUpload()`  method is running in MainThread, which should run in background.

Try following way,

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        doFileUpload()
    }
 });
```

Comment: UI thread is called main thread. Call should be in background thread.

Answer (score 0):

You must upload file in asynctask like this

```
private void doFileUpload() {

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                HttpURLConnection conn = null;
                DataOutputStream dos = null;
                DataInputStream inStream = null;
                String lineEnd = "rn";
                String twoHyphens = "--";
                String boundary = "*****";
                int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
                byte[] buffer;
                int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
                String responseFromServer = "";
                try {
                    // ------------------ CLIENT REQUEST
                    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(selectedPath));
                    // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                    URL url = new URL(urlString);
                    // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
                    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    // Allow Inputs
                    conn.setDoInput(true);
                    // Allow Outputs
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);
                    // Don't use a cached copy.
                    conn.setUseCaches(false);
                    // Use a post method.
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                    dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";name=\"" + selectedPath + "\"" + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    // create a buffer of maximum size
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                    // read file and write it into form...
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    while (bytesRead > 0) {
                        dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    }
                    // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
                    // close streams
                    Log.e("Debug", "File is written");
                    fileInputStream.close();
                    dos.flush();
                    dos.close();
                } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                    Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
                }
                // ------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
                try {
                    inStream = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                    String str;

                    while ((str = inStream.readLine()) != null) {
                        Log.e("Debug", "Server Response " + str);
                    }
                    inStream.close();

                } catch (IOException ioex) {
                    Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
                }

                return null;
            }
        }.execute();

    }
```

Comment: Thanks alot! But now i got a another error. File is written
Server Response There was an error uploading the file, please try again!filename: target_path: uploads/

Comment: Post your full logcat.